# Julia: Parallel for loop over partitions iterator

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

So I'm trying to iterate over the list of partitions of something, say `1:n` for some `n` between 13 and 21. The code that I ideally want to run looks something like this:

```
valid_num = @parallel (+) for p in partitions(1:n)
  int(is_valid(p))
end

println(valid_num)
```

This would use the `@parallel for` to map-reduce my problem. For example, compare this to the example in the Julia documentation:

```
nheads = @parallel (+) for i=1:200000000
  Int(rand(Bool))
end
```

However, if I try my adaptation of the loop, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: `getindex` has no method matching getindex(::SetPartitions{UnitRange{Int64}}, ::Int64)
 in anonymous at no file:1433
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1279
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:621
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:630
 in anonymous at task.jl:6
```

which I think is because I am trying to iterate over something that is not of the form `1:n` (EDIT: I think it's because you cannot call `p[3]` if `p=partitions(1:n)`).

I've tried using `pmap` to solve this, but because the number of partitions can get really big, really quickly (there are more than 2.5 million partitions of `1:13`, and when I get to `1:21` things will be huge), constructing such a large array becomes an issue. I left it running over night and it still didn't finish.

Does anyone have any advice for how I can efficiently do this in Julia? I have access to a ~30 core computer and my task seems easily parallelizable, so I would be really grateful if anyone knows a good way to do this in Julia.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you could replace `for p in partitions(1:n)` with `for p in collect(partitions(1:n))`. However, depending on the size of your problem you might run into memory issues... Also, I'm surprised you can't iterate over the output of `partitions` since I thought that is what [this issue here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/4055) dealt with. Nonetheless, indexing into the output of `partitions` doesn't work on my machine either so I'm obviously missing something...

Comment: I wish I could. If I try `for p in collect(partitions(1:21)))` though, which I know I'll have to do, I run into memory issues :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code gives 511, the number of partitions of size 2 of a set of 10.

```
using Iterators
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
is_valid(p) = length(p)==2
valid_num = @parallel (+) for i = 1:30
  sum(map(is_valid, takenth(chain(1:29,drop(partitions(s), i-1)), 30)))
end
```

This solution combines the takenth, drop, and chain iterators to get the same effect as the take_every iterator below under PREVIOUS ANSWER.  Note that in this solution, every process must compute every partition.  However, because each process uses a different argument to `drop`, no two processes will ever call is_valid on the same partition.

Unless you want to do a lot of math to figure out how to actually skip partitions, there is no way to avoid computing partitions sequentially on at least one process.  I think Simon's answer does this on one process and distributes the partitions.  Mine asks each worker process to compute the partitions itself, which means the computation is being duplicated.  However, it is being duplicated in parallel, which (if you actually have 30 processors) will not cost you time.

Here is a resource on how iterators over partitions are actually computed: http://www.informatik.uni-ulm.de/ni/Lehre/WS03/DMM/Software/partitions.pdf.

### PREVIOUS ANSWER (More complicated than necessary)

I noticed Simon's answer while writing mine.  Our solutions seem similar to me, except mine uses iterators to avoid storing partitions in memory.  I'm not sure which would actually be faster for what size sets, but I figure it's good to have both options.  Assuming it takes you significantly longer to compute is_valid than to compute the partitions themselves, you can do something like this:

```
s = [1,2,3,4]
is_valid(p) = length(p)==2
valid_num = @parallel (+) for i = 1:30
  foldl((x,y)->(x + int(is_valid(y))), 0, take_every(partitions(s), i-1, 30))
end
```

which gives me 7, the number of partitions of size 2 for a set of 4.  The take_every function returns an iterator that returns every 30th partition starting with the ith.  Here is the code for that:

```
import Base: start, done, next
immutable TakeEvery{Itr}
  itr::Itr
  start::Any
  value::Any
  flag::Bool
  skip::Int64
end
function take_every(itr, offset, skip)
  value, state = Nothing, start(itr)
  for i = 1:(offset+1)
    if done(itr, state)
      return TakeEvery(itr, state, value, false, skip)
    end
    value, state = next(itr, state)
  end
  if done(itr, state)
    TakeEvery(itr, state, value, true, skip)
  else
    TakeEvery(itr, state, value, false, skip)
  end
end
function start{Itr}(itr::TakeEvery{Itr})
  itr.value, itr.start, itr.flag
end
function next{Itr}(itr::TakeEvery{Itr}, state)
  value, state_, flag = state
  for i=1:itr.skip
    if done(itr.itr, state_)
      return state[1], (value, state_, false)
    end
    value, state_ = next(itr.itr, state_)
  end
  if done(itr.itr, state_)
    state[1], (value, state_, !flag)
  else
    state[1], (value, state_, false)
  end
end
function done{Itr}(itr::TakeEvery{Itr}, state)
  done(itr.itr, state[2]) && !state[3]
end
```

Comment: The takenth function in the Iterators package (https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl) seems to do what TakeEvery is doing. But looking at your code, I'm wondering why you created a TakeEvery type. I haven't made any data structures yet in Julia, so I'm curious about when to make/not make new data structures.

Comment: Does takenth allow an offset?  It looked like it didn't to me, which is why I made my own.  I always prefer to not make my own data structures if possible, but Julia is so new that sometimes the features I need aren't implemented yet.  I also just don't have that much knowledge of what is out there in the Julia ecosystem.

Comment: Oh, but it looks like they have a drop function, which you could combine with takenth to get what you want.

Comment: Edited my answer to use takenth, drop, and chain instead of take_every.

Comment: Why do you use chain(1:29, ...)?

Comment: The takenth iterator starts by taking the nth partition.  That is, it takes iterator[i] where i % n == 0.  What I wanted in this case was for it to start by taking the first item, then the (n+1)th, and so on.  That is, I wanted it to take iterator[i] where i % n == 1.  My solution was just to pad the beginning of the iterator with the appropriate number of extra items, none of which will actually be used.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Also, if anyone was curious, I tried jcrudy's solution (for just one set of genes) and it took... 18 hours. Welp.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to divide the problem up into pieces that are not too big to realize and then process the items within each piece in parallel, e.g. as follows:

```
function my_take(iter,state,n)
    i = n
    arr = Array[]
    while !done(iter,state) && (i>0)
        a,state = next(iter,state)
        push!(arr,a)
        i = i-1
    end
    return arr, state
end

function get_part(npart,npar)
    valid_num = 0
    p = partitions(1:npart)
    s = start(p)
    while !done(p,s)
        arr,s = my_take(p,s,npar)
        valid_num += @parallel (+) for a in arr
            length(a)
        end
    end
    return valid_num
end

valid_num = @time get_part(10,30)
```

I was going to use the [take()](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/#Base.take) method to realize up to `npar` items from the iterator but `take()` appears to be deprecated so I've included my own implementation which I've called `my_take()`. The `getPart()` function therefore uses `my_take()` to obtain up to `npar` partitions at a time and carry out a calculation on them. In this case, the calculation just adds up their lengths, because I don't have the code for the OP's `is_valid()` function. `get_part()` then returns the result.

Because the `length()` calculation isn't very time-consuming, this code is actually slower when run on parallel processors than it is on a single processor:

```
$ julia -p 1 parpart.jl
elapsed time: 10.708567515 seconds (373025568 bytes allocated, 6.79% gc time)

$ julia -p 2 parpart.jl
elapsed time: 15.70633439 seconds (548394872 bytes allocated, 9.14% gc time)
```

Alternatively, `pmap()` could be used on each piece of the problem instead of the parallel `for` loop.

With respect to the memory issue, realizing 30 items from `partitions(1:10)` took nearly 1 gigabyte of memory on my PC when I ran Julia with 4 worker processes so I expect realizing even a small subset of `partitions(1:21)` will require a great deal of memory. It may be desirable to estimate how much memory would be needed to see if it would be at all possible before trying such a computation.

With respect to the computation time, note that:

```
julia> length(partitions(1:10))
115975

julia> length(partitions(1:21))
474869816156751
```

... so even efficient parallel processing on 30 cores might not be enough to make the larger problem solvable in a reasonable time.

Comment: Awesome! Interestingly, I just noticed that when I use the Iterators package, take is no longer deprecated. You'd have to repeatedly call take and drop if you use it; it'd be interesting to see how this fairs against your `my_take` method. I have a hunch yours would be faster.

Comment: Also if anyone's curious, I tried Simon's solution for a set of size 15 (I also only checked up to partitions of size 5, since I wanted to avoid partitions which had a part of size <2). It ran the whole night and still didn't finish; I think because doing too many parallel computations takes a lot of time, since the threads have to communicate with one another.

Comment: @Uthsav Chitra: Thanks for the feedback. The only communication between threads in my approach is between the single thread that calculates the partitions and the parallel threads that check validity (or length, in my example), and the fact that all the parallel threads have to complete. However, with a set of size 15, the amount of memory required to realize (say) 30 partitions at a time might still be larger than the available RAM. jcrudy's solution that only realizes one partition at a time for each processor seems to be avoiding that difficulty. Good to see you have a solution.